# what happens when you copy vector<boost::share_ptr> to another vector

Tags: c++, boost, vector

Do we get multiple copies of the pointers yet the data members are still being shared?

```
  boost::shared_ptr<string> a1(new string("Hello"));  
  vector<boost::shared_ptr<string> > a;  
  a.push_back(a1);  

  vector<boost::shared_ptr<string> > b;  
  b = a;

 cout<<a[0]->c_str()<<b[0]->c_str()<<endl;  

 a1->append(" World");  

 cout<<a[0]->c_str()<<b[0]->c_str()<<endl;
```

Output:
HelloHello
Hello WorldHello World

Comment: If we didn't, what would be the point of the shared_ptr class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  But don't take my word for it, try it and see.

Comment: wrote a quick test .. and you are right.. just wanted to share this that's why asked the question on the SO. :)